# Correct word for a design in progress

Tags: single-word-requests

In the process of making a design, what is the design called? (Specifically in regard to graphic design)

As in:

> Please see first design(??) of poster attached

Comment: We're really trying to avoid using this site for "single word requests" where a dictionary, thesaurus or reverse-dictionary lookup will suffice. If you have a particularly *interesting* problem to solve, all we ask is that you put a bit of effort and research into the question. See: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests/1737#1737 or http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity

Comment: Sorry about that, I'm still learning my way around here :)

Comment: No problem. It's a legacy problem that we're just trying to understand and address positively.

Comment: @RobertCartaino: Do you really think this particular question is solvable by a dictionary/thesaurus/reverse-dictionary? I don't think so.

Comment: @Mitch Please read the meta discussion here: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity. Do you think this meets the criteria outlined? Or do you disagree there is a quality problem at all?

Comment: @Robert Cartaino: My pardons to the OP, but yes I find there are quality problems with this question, but not 'not a real question' or 'general reference'. Re the meta-question, I don't think this question is googlable (to oversimplify).

Comment: @Mitch "General Reference" was never mentioned in that meta post because this isn't really about "Can it be Googled?" (I agree, that would be a dangerous criteria to reject questions) -- This is about whether these *types* of questions will continue to be acceptable on this site. The consensus (see links in my first comment) seems to be "no question of this type" unless there is significant research and effort put in to the asking... to *make* them interesting.

Comment: @RobertCartaino: Rereading that meta question, it looks like one of its primary issues is googlability. Second, if your criterion is effort put into a question (like thought/research/googling/whatever), the great majority of questions should be closed -before- you get to this one (I'm not saying all those and this one should stay, just that this one isn't near the worst). I wouldn't be unhappy if you went ahead and closed a number of them yourself right now, I'm just wonder why you skipped the many to land on this particular one that isn't so bad.

Comment: @Mitch No, certainly this is not the worst. This has been an on-going problem with this site that I've been asked to step up and rein in (see Shog's very recent [meta post](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2160/single-word-requests-crosswords-and-the-fight-against-mediocrity)). The consensus is that there are too many questions that are bad for this site but there hasn't been enough community activity to keep the bar on those questions high enough.

Comment: +1 : as a browser of the questions, I thought this was interesting & vote reopen

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question, this is usually referred to as a [*comp*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comprehensive_layout):

> In graphic design and advertising, a *comprehensive layout* or
>   *comprehensive*, usually shortened to *comp*, is the page layout of a
>   proposed design as initially presented by the designer to a client,
>   showing the relative positions of text and illustrations before the
>   specific content of those elements has been decided on, as a rough
>   draft of the final layout in which to build around.

Comment: Thanks, seems to be what I'm looking for! However, once you design a comp, what would you refer to it as as you make revisions until you have finalized it? A revision perhaps?

Comment: Design clients tend to be less technical, so _version_ is normally preferred.